# Calculator (Android-Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Started to study android development, trying to write a simple calculator.
Here is the code (and it works)

```
 public void Plus (View view) {

        EditText field1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
        EditText field2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
        TextView resultField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        double num1 = Double.valueOf(field1.getText().toString());
        double num2 = Double.valueOf(field2.getText().toString());
        double result = num1 + num2;
        DecimalFormat formatVal = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
        resultField.setText(formatVal.format(result));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

But without DecimalFormat function it does not works.
I tried
`resultField.setText((result))` and got an error.
Is it possible to avoid using Decimal format or no?

Comment: What error did you get when you removed the `DecimalFormat`?

Comment: First try `resultField.setText(String.valueOf(result))` - without the string it likely doesn't compile (or it thinks it is a resource id if converted to int).

Comment: Mureinik, app closed due to some unknown error.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines that causes the problem.

```java
double num1 = Double.valueOf(field1.getText().toString());
double num2 = Double.valueOf(field2.getText().toString());
```

Yes, `NumberFormatException` will be thrown because you're trying to convert an empty string to double. Yet the worst part is, those two lines shouldn't to be there at first place. It too early. You'll need to enter inputs to the `EditText` first before even trying to do any convertions.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your **Double** before to set it as text in a **TextView**, that's the main problem, here's a working code of your calculator, hope it helps, keep coding buddy!

```
public void Plus () {

    EditText field1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num1);
    EditText field2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num2);
    TextView resultField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(field1.getText().toString());
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(field2.getText().toString());
    double result = num1 + num2;
    String string = Double.toString(result);
    resultField.setText(string);

}
```